# best practises to increase TensorFlow object detection accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

I am following a very good object detection tutorial at youtube "Intro - TensorFlow Object Detection API Tutorial" divided in 6 parts.

I am using default train.py of "models\research\object_detection". Before running train.py I have a) collected 500 raw JPG images, b) labeled them using labelimg, c) converted them to CSV file, d) created TFRecord from CSV.

Beside increasing number of raw images what should I do to increase accuracy?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on your problem: what kind of classes you have, how many, how hard the problem is for a computer... In any case you should compare your training and testing accuracies: in short, if you're much better on the training dataset, then you should reduce the capacity if your network (reduce network size, training epochs, add regularizers, etc); if both are close but not good enough you should do the opposite. But as you already know, getting more data is probably the best you can do here.

Comment: i want to find whether a .JPG image has an ISBN number present vertically/horizontally at any place of the image. As i have already done the following steps - a) collected 500 raw JPG images, b) labeled them using labelimg, c) converted them to CSV file, d) created TFRecord from CSV. While labeling I have marked the isbn position vertically/horizontally but assigned them to a single class called isbn_tracker_label. So far I have not needed a single line of code and just used sample codes. Do i need to write any customised algorithm?